# Change php text box to button

Tags: php, javascript, html

The code below displays a text box on, for example page1.php.

How can I get this to be a button that will open a new php page, and have a done button that will take them back to page1.php and populate the value or create a popup box with bullets and a done button.

```
if ($editmodeison) print("<td class='content' align='center'><input type=\"text\"name=\"edit[$k]\" value=\"" . ( !empty( $row[$k] )?htmlspecialchars( $row[$k] ) : htmlspecialchars( '' ) ) . "\" /></td>\n");
```

I also tried this:

```
if ($editmodeison) print("<td class='content' align='center'><input type=\"button\" name=\"edit[$k]\" onclick='window.location.href="http://localhost/page2.php"value=\"$score" . ( !empty( $row[$k] )?htmlspecialchars( $row[$k] ) : htmlspecialchars( '' ) ) . "\" /></td>\n");
```

I tried to redirect it to page 2 and I am using a `$_GET` to pull it from the URL. The error I get is:

> syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /home/content/59/11513559/html/bg/page1.php on line 87

Comment: You have like 15 questions there and answering them would require an essay... Please make your question clear and concise: what is the problem and what's not working? We solve problems here, not do others' homeworks.

Comment: I have one question with 2 possible scenarios.

Comment: As the previous person mentioned, please make your question more concise. Looking at what you're attempting to do I would recommend using jquery over trying to print the button. 

But if you want an answer to the first part of your question(s)...


Use the onClick method and change your input type from "text" to "button"


(Pseudo Code)
`
print( "<td class='content' align='center'><input type=\"button\"name=\"edit[$k]\" value=\"" . ( !empty( $row[$k] )?htmlspecialchars( $row[$k] ) : htmlspecialchars( '' ) ) . "\" onClick="window.open('[INSERT URL TO PHP PAGE]')" /></td>\n" );
`

Comment: I simplified it and added what i tried.

Comment: @nerdworx I tried your example and stil get the same error as above

Comment: Escape the " characters in the URL. The joys of pseudo code :) 


if ($editmodeison) print("<td class='content' align='center'><input type=\"button\" name=\"edit[$k]\" onclick='window.location.href=\"http://localhost/page2.php\"value=\"$score" . ( !empty( $row[$k] )?htmlspecialchars( $row[$k] ) : htmlspecialchars( '' ) ) . "\" /></td>\n");

Also if you're trying to send $score value to page 2, you need to pass it as a query parameter.

Comment: Sorry about that, No i am not trying to pass the $score to the new page. What i thought i had to do is assign a variable to the value. that way when the new page passes data to the current php page the value would be set. now i think about it i am wrong.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear! I moved my comment to the answer, you can click Answered to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($editmodeison) print("<td class='content' align='center'><input type=\"button\" name=\"edit[$k]\" onclick='window.location.href=\"localhost/page2.php\"value=\"$score" . ( !empty( $row[$k] )?htmlspecialchars( $row[$k] ) : htmlspecialchars( '' ) ) . "\" /></td>\n");
```